# Unable to assign a subdomain on Route 53 to an Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

As I'm nearing the end of my project, I'm setting up duplicate environments to easily manage dev and prod.

The backend is a NodeJS docker that runs on EB. The admin panel is a webserver that runs on NodeJS. The EB instance runs on a domain name that I manage on Route 53 (for this example : https://www.myproject.com)

**What works** :

When I go to https://www.myproject.com, I see my admin panel. It is exactly the same as if I click on my EB URL (minus the SSL certificate stuff which doesnt work on that URL, only the domain name) [image]

**What doesn't work** :

This exact same setup, but instead of associating it to a domain name, I associate it to a subdomain like https://dev.myproject.com . In route 53, I created an A record that points to the EB loadbalancer (exactly what I did for the other one) but it doesn't work (always returns "server IP address could not be found. / DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". I also tried associating the A record with the EB URL (the one from the screenshot) but this doesn't work either (same result). Accessing that EB URL directly does work so at least I'm 100% sure the EB instance is OK and it's most likely a config within Route 53.

**Recap**

**myproject.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com** is set up to redirect to https://www.myproject.com. The A record in Route 53 points to the load balancer of that EB instance. This works.

**myproject-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com** is setup to redirect to https://www.dev.myproject.com. The A record in Route 53 points to the load balancer of that EB instance. This doesn't work.

What could I be doing wrong? Any clues?

Comment: One week later update : I have never been able to solve this issue and simply used another domain name for dev instead of assigning it to a subdomain. That works fine..